# How to configure Lychee server? apache error 500

Tags: php, apache-2.4, httpd

os AlmaLinux 9.1
Apache/2.4.53
PHP 8.2.4

try to install Lychee with postgreesql
my httpd.conf

```
    ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName 192.168.90.20:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Lychee/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/Lychee/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

my .env file for Lychee

```
APP_NAME=My Photographies
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:bla_bls_bla=
APP_DEBUG=True
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_FORCE_HTTPS=false


DB_OLD_LYCHEE_PREFIX=

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=Lychee
DB_USERNAME=lychee
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
DB_LOG_SQL=True


DB_LIST_FOREIGN_KEYS=true

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
# `sync` if jobs needs to be executed live (default) or `database` if they can be defered.
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

SECURITY_HEADER_HSTS_ENABLE=false
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=

TRUSTED_PROXIES=null
```

os AlmaLinux 9.1 Apache/2.4.53 PHP 8.2.4

try to install Lychee with postgreesql httpd.conf:

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName 192.168.90.20:80

AllowOverride none
Require all denied

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Lychee/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/Lychee/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted


DirectoryIndex index.html

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b" common

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i" %I %O" combinedio

CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined


ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted


TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

when i try to open my website( http://192.168.90.20 and http://192.168.90.20/index.php) i get empty page. Nothing

in /var/log/httpd/access_log I see:

```
[25/Apr/2023:10:56:31 +0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
 [25/Apr/2023:10:56:44 +0500] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
```

in /var/log/httpd/error_log (with log_level = debug) I see:

```
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.644022 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4989:tid 4989] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.644753 2023] [suexec:notice] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.644766 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01883: Init: Initialized OpenSSL library
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.646033 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.648952 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.53 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.53, Library: OpenSSL/3.0.1
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.648985 2023] [http2:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_http2.c(111): AH03089: initializing post config dry run
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.659049 2023] [so:warn] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01574: module systemd_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660626 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01883: Init: Initialized OpenSSL library
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660654 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(414): AH00821: shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660658 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(428): AH00822: for 511912 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 88 indexes each
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660661 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(465): AH00824: shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660664 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(467): AH00825: subcache_num = 32
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660666 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(469): AH00826: subcache_size = 15992
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660669 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(471): AH00827: subcache_data_offset = 2128
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660671 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(473): AH00828: subcache_data_size = 13864
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660673 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_socache_shmcb.c(475): AH00829: index_num = 88
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660729 2023] [socache_shmcb:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.660732 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.663823 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.53 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.53, Library: OpenSSL/3.0.1
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.663855 2023] [slotmem_shm:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_slotmem_shm.c(495): AH02301: attach looking for /etc/httpd/run/slotmem-shm-mod_heartmonitor_0.shm
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.663869 2023] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665334 2023] [http2:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH03090: mod_http2 (v1.15.19-git, feats=CHPRIO+SHA256+INVHD+DWINS, nghttp2 1.43.0), initializing...
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665379 2023] [fcgid:info] [pid 4991:tid 4991] mod_fcgid: Process manager 4991 started
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665396 2023] [proxy_http2:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH03349: mod_proxy_http2 (v1.15.19-git, nghttp2 1.43.0), initializing...
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665414 2023] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(1127): AH03265: watchdog callback registered (_proxy_hcheck_ for 192.168.90.20)
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665442 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(445): AH010033: Watchdog: Running with WatchdogInterval 1000ms
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665449 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(454): AH02974: Watchdog: found parent providers.
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665453 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(500): AH02977: Watchdog: found child providers.
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665456 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_singleton_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665459 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_default_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665462 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(508): AH02978: Watchdog: Looking for child (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.665481 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] mod_watchdog.c(534): AH02979: Watchdog: Created singleton mutex (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.666555 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] event.c(740): Child 0 started: pid 4992, gen 0, active 1/16, total 1/1/16
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.666991 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] event.c(740): Child 1 started: pid 4993, gen 0, active 2/16, total 2/2/16
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.667677 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] event.c(740): Child 2 started: pid 4994, gen 0, active 3/16, total 3/3/16
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.667697 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH00489: Apache/2.4.53 (AlmaLinux) OpenSSL/3.0.1 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.667713 2023] [mpm_event:info] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH00490: Server built: Mar 16 2023 00:00:00
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.667728 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4989:tid 4989] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.667734 2023] [core:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] log.c(1574): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668379 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4992] mod_watchdog.c(582): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668397 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4995] mod_watchdog.c(168): AH02972: Singleton Watchdog (_proxy_hcheck_) running
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668410 2023] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4995] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(962): AH03258: _proxy_hcheck_ watchdog started.
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668478 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4992] proxy_util.c(2123): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668513 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4992] proxy_util.c(2183): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668542 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4992] proxy_util.c(2214): AH00930: initialized pool in child 4992 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668760 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4993:tid 4993] mod_watchdog.c(582): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668800 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 4993] proxy_util.c(2123): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668813 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 4993] proxy_util.c(2183): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.668820 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 4993] proxy_util.c(2214): AH00930: initialized pool in child 4993 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669283 2023] [proxy_hcheck:debug] [pid 4992:tid 4995] mod_proxy_hcheck.c(976): AH03313: apr_thread_pool_create() with 16 threads succeeded
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669307 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 4994:tid 4994] mod_watchdog.c(582): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669354 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4994:tid 4994] proxy_util.c(2123): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669368 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4994:tid 4994] proxy_util.c(2183): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local

[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669376 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4994:tid 4994] proxy_util.c(2214): AH00930: initialized pool in child 4994 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669899 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4992:tid 5103] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.669924 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5105] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Apr 25 10:55:20.670481 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4994:tid 5143] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700260 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700286 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700350 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700355 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700386 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700390 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700445 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_proxy.c(1517): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700473 2023] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_proxy_ajp.c(780): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH00894: declining URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700479 2023] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1055): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700483 2023] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1064): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700492 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(2532): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700497 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(2588): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php to localhost:8000
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700501 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(2624): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /run/php-fpm/www.sock
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700587 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(2814): [client 192.168.90.10:50842] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.700614 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(3182): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.741655 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 4989:tid 4989] event.c(740): Child 3 started: pid 5215, gen 0, active 4/16, total 4/4/16
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.743577 2023] [watchdog:debug] [pid 5215:tid 5215] mod_watchdog.c(582): AH02981: Watchdog: Created child worker thread (_proxy_hcheck_).
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.743632 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 5215:tid 5215] proxy_util.c(2123): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.743647 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 5215:tid 5215] proxy_util.c(2183): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.743656 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 5215:tid 5215] proxy_util.c(2214): AH00930: initialized pool in child 5215 for (*) min=0 max=61 smax=61
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.744687 2023] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 5215:tid 5254] event.c(2401): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:31.749557 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5110] proxy_util.c(2547): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520605 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520625 2023] [authz_core:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520662 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_proxy.c(1517): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520667 2023] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_proxy_ajp.c(780): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH00894: declining URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520671 2023] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1055): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520674 2023] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1064): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520678 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(2532): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520683 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(2588): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php to localhost:8000
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520692 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(2624): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /run/php-fpm/www.sock
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520775 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(2814): [client 192.168.90.10:50844] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/Lychee/public/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.520802 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(3182): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*)
[Tue Apr 25 10:56:44.568852 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 4993:tid 5116] proxy_util.c(2547): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

I tested apache with simple index.html with javascript etc - all worked o'key
tested with dummy php - work!

i don't know what I nedd to do to solve this problem